# SQLite query to read an XML file

Tags: sqlite

I want a SQLite query for reading my XML file and then I want a function that will convert my XML file to an SQLite table.

Comment: What code do you got so far, what language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There's no query or function to do this.
The way to go is to write a stylesheet (`.xsl`) that produces output consumable by sqlite's `.import` command.

Comment: Or even use the XSLT to generate SQL INSERT statements (although this can be a bit fiddly in practice, certainly with XSLT 1.0).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to read XML using SQLite commands, but you can create your own function which takes an XML path as parameter. Follow these steps,
assuming that you are using .NET, and you know the structure of the XML (nodes, elements and attributes):

1. Load the XML in `XmlDocument`, so that you can read the XML elements.
2. Iterate one `for` loop for number of times equal to the node count in XML.
3. Build one dynamic string which prepares the `insert` command in SQLite, with all the required node values as column values.
4. Execute the dynamically prepared `insert` command in SQlite.